# java game saving program wont work

Tags: java

so i am currently making a game (a huge one over 3500 lines of code) and when programing the saving feature of the game i ran into an error.it saves just fine but when i try to load one of the files that i saved the game to it returns an error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.torstein.Mars_Settlement.States.Building.Parse(Building.java:56)
    at com.torstein.Mars_Settlement.Managers.SavingManager.Load(SavingManager.java:102)
    at com.torstein.Mars_Settlement.SLGUI$2.actionPerformed(SLGUI.java:155)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
```

and so on...

it is basicly saying that the Scanner i use to scan the file is returning "". i have checked over source code many times but i cant get i to work. here is the SavingManager Class:

```
package com.torstein.Mars_Settlement.Managers;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.torstein.Mars_Settlement.Bases;
import com.torstein.Mars_Settlement.Connection;
import com.torstein.Mars_Settlement.Main;
import com.torstein.Mars_Settlement.Eneties.CarEnety;
import com.torstein.Mars_Settlement.Eneties.LightGunnerEntity;
import com.torstein.Mars_Settlement.Eneties.Pepole;
import com.torstein.Mars_Settlement.Eneties.Plant;
import com.torstein.Mars_Settlement.Eneties.TankEntity;
import com.torstein.Mars_Settlement.States.Building;
import com.torstein.Mars_Settlement.States.GroundState;

public class SavingManager {

    public static void Save(String Path){
        Main m = Main.UseThis;
        File txt = new File(Path);
        txt.delete();
        Formatter f = null;
        try {
            f = new Formatter(Path);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        f.format("%d%n",m.pepoleOut);
        for(Bases b : m.bases)
            f.format(b.toString()+"%n");
        f.format(":%n");
        f.format(m.Fusion+"%n");
        f.format(m.Compact+"%n");
        f.format(m.Money+"%n");
        f.format(m.Water+"%n");
        f.format(m.Energy+"%n");
        f.format(m.Food+"%n");
        f.format(m.Venus+"%n");
        for(int x = 0;x<20;x++)
            for(int y = 0;y<20;y++)
                f.format(m.stateG[x][y].T+"%n");
        for(int x = 0;x<20;x++)
            for(int y = 0;y<20;y++)
                f.format(m.stateB[x][y].toString()+"%n");
        f.format(m.Terraformed+"%n");

        for(CarEnety b : m.cars)
            f.format(b.toString()+"%n");
        f.format(":%n");

        for(Pepole b : m.Pepole)
            f.format(b.toString()+"%n");
        f.format(":%n");

        for(Plant b : m.plants)
            f.format(b.toString()+"%n");
        f.format(":%n");

        for(Connection b : m.Connections)
            f.format(b.toString()+"%n");
        f.format(":%n");
        for(TankEntity b : m.Tanks)
            f.format(b.toString()+"%n");
        f.format(":%n");
        for(LightGunnerEntity b : m.LightGunners)
            f.format(b.toString()+"%n");
        f.format(":%n");

        f.close();
    }
    public static void Load(String Path){
        final Main m = Main.UseThis;
        m.Contiuecapable=true;
        m.Treset();
        Scanner scan = null;
        try {
            scan = new Scanner(new File(Path));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String cln;
        m.pepoleOut = scan.nextInt();
        while(!(cln = scan.nextLine()).startsWith(":"))
            if(Bases.parseBase(cln)!=null)m.bases.add(Bases.parseBase(cln));
        m.Fusion = scan.nextBoolean();
        m.Compact = scan.nextBoolean();
        m.Money = scan.nextInt();
        m.Water = scan.nextInt();
        m.Energy = scan.nextInt();
        m.Food = scan.nextInt();
        m.Venus = scan.nextBoolean();
        for(int x = 0;x<20;x++)
            for(int y = 0;y<20;y++)
                m.stateG[x][y]=GroundState.Parse(scan.nextInt());


        for(int x = 0;x<20;x++)
            for(int y = 0;y<20;y++)
            {

                m.stateB[x][y]= Building.Parse(scan.nextLine());
                if(m.stateB[x][y].index==6)
                    m.addHouseSpirit(x,y);
            }

        m.Terraformed = scan.nextBoolean();
        while(!(cln = scan.nextLine()).startsWith(":"))
            if(CarEnety.Parse(cln)!=null)m.cars.add(CarEnety.Parse(cln));
        while(!(cln = scan.nextLine()).startsWith(":"))
            if(Pepole.Parse(cln)!=null)m.Pepole.add(Pepole.Parse(cln));
        while(!(cln = scan.nextLine()).startsWith(":"))
            if(Plant.Parse(cln)!=null)m.plants.add(Plant.Parse(cln));
        while(!(cln = scan.nextLine()).startsWith(":"))
            if(Connection.Parse(cln)!=null)m.Connections.add(Connection.Parse(cln));
        while(!(cln = scan.nextLine()).startsWith(":"))
            if(TankEntity.Parse(cln)!=null)m.Tanks.add(TankEntity.Parse(cln));
        while(!(cln = scan.nextLine()).startsWith(":"))
            if(LightGunnerEntity.Parse(cln)!=null)m.LightGunners.add(LightGunnerEntity.Parse(cln));

        scan.close();
    }

}
```

File content that im trying to parse:

```
0
R:4:4:0:false
:
false
false
1000
1000
500
1000
false
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
2
0
3
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
0
0
1
0
3
0
2
0
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
0:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
-1:100:0:1
false
:
:
:
:
:
:
```

Building.Parse:

```
public static Building Parse(String parsef){

        int id = Integer.parseInt(parsef.split(":")[0]);
        Building b =id == -1 ? No :
        id == 0 ? Base :
        id == 1 ? UranCollectorBase :
        id == 2 ? IceCollectorBase :
        id == 3 ? NuclearReactor :
        id == 4 ? House :
        id == 5 ? IceMeltor :
        id == 6 ? GunHouse :
        id == 7 ? ResearchCenter :
        id == 8 ? GBase :
        id == 9 ? SBase :
        id == 10 ? MBase :
        id == 11 ? FlowerCollector :
        id == 12 ? WindMill :
        id == 13 ? VechleProduser :
        id == 14 ? OBase :
        No;
        b.health = Integer.parseInt(parsef.split(":")[1]);
        b.Tanks = Integer.parseInt(parsef.split(":")[2]);
        b.lookfor=carStates.Parse(Integer.parseInt(parsef.split(":")[3]));
        return b;
    }
```

if there is anything else you will have to need to fix this error please say so. Thanks for your time. Torstein.

Comment: What did you learn when you ran this in the debugger?

Comment: that the scanner still has input just before the error acured, it stoped loading at the very fisrt element of the loop and that is basicly all the important stuff i noiced

Comment: Ok.  I think if you want to get useful help here, you'll need to reduce this to a minimal test case that exhibits the problem (see http://sscce.org).

Comment: Can you share the file content that you are parsing?

Comment: ok i will remove the imports and the save method

Comment: @JProgrammer it is over 800 lines... when i fisrt started programing this last summer i didnt think i would ever have to ask but i sure could..

Comment: Have you tried skipping that particular input? I think, when statement scan.nextInt() in for loop { GroundState.Parse(scan.nextInt()) } executed last time , the file reading pointer is at the end of the line. Then call to nextLine() will return "" (empty string). So what you need to do is just skip this particular empty string from processing.

Comment: 1) That's not an [sscce](http://sscce.org) since we can neither compile nor run your code. If you don't get a solution soon and if this is important to you, consider reading through the [sscce](http://sscce.org) and creating and posting one. It takes some effort to do, but in the end is usually worth it. 2) Your data file has a lot of similar data. I wonder if it could be "smarter" and thus shorter using a sparse array of some sort.

Comment: You will at least have to supply the `Building.Parse` method since that is where the exception occurs. Without it we can only guess...

Comment: Ok. @JProgrammer like this scan.skip("");? cuz that didnt work...

Comment: inline = scan.nextLine();
if(inline.trim().length() != 0){
     // your code here
}

I executed your program with my code modification and it worked on my end.

Comment: @Hovercarft if you want to run it yourself, just download the eclpise project as it is a quite big and many images required for it to work.and i promise from the bottom of my heart that it is not a virus. link http://www.mediafire.com/?3cc5tc51ftcz8bq

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but: 3500 lines of code is not a huge program

Comment: yeah but there is also something called images and textfiles and as a thirteen year old boy i have a life outside programing games.

Comment: @JProgrammer can you please post that skipping thing as an awnser? because then i could accept it, because well, that was the proper awnser to me ;)

Comment: @TorsteinVik I have posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, when statement scan.nextInt() in for loop { GroundState.Parse(scan.nextInt()) } executed last time , the file reading pointer is at the end of the line. Then call to nextLine() will return "" (empty string). So what you need to do is just skip this particular empty string from processing.

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother writing your own object persistence code - there are existing solutions for that.  For your data I suggest that you store the state of the game as an object. Use JAXB to marshal the object (i.e. write to disk as XML) and unmarshal the object (i.e. create the object by reading the XML file).

JAXB is not very hard to use. You can read up on it at the [JAXB reference implementation](http://jaxb.java.net/) page. I'm a fan of EclipseLink's JAXB provider, MOXy. They have a very easy-to-follow [getting started tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/TheBasics).

As a bonus, when you store your save game file in XML you'll be able to open it with any text editor and easily read the state of the game. This will make debugging your game much easier as game state will be human readable. With your current format you'll have to count lines to look up values.

If you don't like XML then use a Java properties file - even that will be better than just raw values.